# Show page in DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to get div content from another page (.html) and display it with the styling of my page.

The div height should size depending on the content since it's aligned to the bottom of the page and needs to stay like this.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: which div content? there could be thousand div's in the page. all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have the content from the remote file styled with your local styles, you would either have to load your styles into an iframe containing that remote file (removing any competing stylesheets), or load the content from the remote file into your local file. The later is probably easier.

Many tools exist online to assist you in doing this. For instance, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) (world's most popular JavaScript library) can asynchronously load a remote file and then add portions of it to the parent document:

```javascript
$("#page").load("remote.html #content");
```

This would grab the contents of `#content` on page `remote.html`, and place them within `#page` on the current page.

Comment: THank you - is this possible without js?

Comment: @Zettam Yes, but it is not possible with *pure HTML*. You could also merge output with a server-side script if you like. HTML cannot pull in parts of other documents like this (outside of `iframe` elements).