# cannot get information from a div into a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi my problem is that I am trying to get a couple Div's from a page into a second page using JQuery I have looked at different links for trying to get a HTML page to be put into a div links such as

[page into div link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204546/show-page-in-div)

[page into div link 2](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?28882-Load-external-page-into-lt-DIV-gt)

Now the problem that I have got is that I have PHP pages and this does not seem to work I have a feeling it is because of how I output the HTML using `echo`

I have tried using jquery and ajax for this and neither of them seem to bring anything back at all.

my code at the moment is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#test").load("test.html"); 
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    echo "<div class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\" role=\"navigation\">";
        echo "<div class=\"container-fluid\">";
            echo "<div class=\"navbar-header\">";
                    echo "<a class=\"navbar-brand\" href=\"#\">The Careers In The Classroom</a>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class=\"navbar-collapse collapse\">";
                    echo "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Dashboard</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Help</a></li>";
                    echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";  
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class=\"container-fluid\">";
        echo "<div class=\"row\">";

            echo "<div class=\"col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar\">";
                echo "<ul class=\"nav nav-sidebar\">";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"content.php\">Media</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"contributors.php\">Users</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a href=\"\">Other</a></li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class=\"col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main\">";
                echo "<h1 class=\"page-header\">Dashboard</h1>";
                echo "<h2 class=\"sub-header\">Section title</h2>";
                echo "<div class=\"table-responsive\">";
                    echo "<table id=\"\">"; 

                    echo "<div id=\"test\">"; 
                    echo "</div>";


                    echo "</table>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.html has a div called content and this has a line of text saying hello 
i have tested this by trying to retrieve the div from a html and a php page and neither seem to bring back any results

and I have also tried and php `include()` this cannot be used due to only needing specific divs instead of the whole page

any ideas or help would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps it's not that important, but you should do `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#test").load("test.html"); });`, else I'm not even sure you can call jQuery. Try adding, before your $("#test").load, a `if (jQuery) { alert ("jQuery!"); }`. If it's not alerting, then add `$(document).ready(function(){ // place your script });`.. Also, if you want to script to be loaded only once everything has been loaded, use `$(window).ready(function(){ $(document).ready(function(){ // you script }); });

Comment: So currently, does it load the complete test.html into your `test` div or does it simply not do anything at all? What is the current situation?

Comment: @briosheje i have actually tried this process with the `$(document).ready(function(){` part in the JQuery I forgot to put it back in for my example

Comment: @AndreschSerj: from what he said: 'i have tested this by trying to retrieve the div from a html and a php page and neither seem to bring back any results' I'm supposing that jQuery is actually NOT working at all, since he is calling the script before the page has been loaded..

Comment: @user3387522: Have you tried to do the alert above? is it working? it's important to be sure that jQuery is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @briosheje it is bringing back the alert so the JQuery is working

Comment: found the error: you have multiple divs with the same ID, don't you?

Comment: @briosheje no i do have a table id and a div id that are the same but i have also removed the table id and it still does nothing

Comment: Ok, so, if you don't have anymore double divs and jQuery is loading correctly, then are you SURE that the file 'test.html' exists? is it located in the same directory as the current page? have you checked your browser javascript console? if jQuery is NOT going to load the page it is going to tell you that in the console log ;)

Comment: @briosheje yes the test.html is in the root and so is the main page the browsers javascript is on because i have javascript elements on other pages that work correctly and there are no errors within the console log

Comment: Then I can't go any further. Try to load the page elsewhere in a static div not loaded with PHP and, if it is working, then that means that the div #test is not yet loaded when the document is ready, therefore you should add `$('#test').ready(function() { });` too, but I personally don't think that's the case.. There must be something else going wrong. In any case, you shouldn't have any `<div>` into a `<table>` tag..

Comment: @briosheje I have removed the table and i only have the `<div>` the
`$(document).ready(function(){ // place your script });` has been added and i have tried this from a static html page to another static html page and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure test.html is accessible to your script means they should reside in the same directory. You can also test it like

```
http://localhost/somedirectory/test.html
```

Comment: I ran your code on my pc and it seems to be loading whatever page i specify in the load method onto the test div. Check for any error after page is loaded

Comment: I have now got this working I'm not sure what the problem was I started the page again and pasted all of the sections with all of the answers and it is partially working now it is just my php functions that need sorting out @user34933486

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use the `echo <<<_END`
and then your html code.
then to end that section add `_END;`
i think you can replace the tag name "END" with anything that is not a reserved word.
this code should be on it's own line and should not be proceeded by anything.
so:

```
<?php
echo <<<_END
    <body>
        <more html>
        </more html>
    </body>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: would this mean that i do no need to use the `echo "";` for each line and just write the html as i normally would ??

Comment: @user3387522 yes, give that a try. if you want to have a php section that is php and not html you can end the _END section and then add your php, then start a new _END section with more html...and on and on.

Comment: this has helped a lot with cutting down the echoes